# Strange behaviour of @Configuration with @Configurable in Spring

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, components, configurable

I've been using XML based configuration for a while - we've got a Vaadin application with Spring used as DI, but we are not interested in `DispacherServlet` - only root context, which we use to inject global (not user owned dependencies).

**The way it works**
I've defined `root-context.xml` file with content:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

And my `web.xml` has in it:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then, some of my classes are defined with `@Component` annotation and others with `@Configurable` (the latter mostly belong to user session, so require DI for each instance created with `new` keyword).

I've got `context.xml` file with line:

```
<Loader delegate="false" loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader" />
```

And `spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar` in Tomcat's `lib` directory.
All the dependencies are injected (with `@Autowire`) to my `@Configurable` classes correctly.


**The way it doesn't work**

Recently I've tried to get rid of `root-context.xml` and move context initialisation to Java `@Configuration` class.
I've created a class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class BeansConfiguration
{
}
```

In addition I changed `web.xml` entries:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.spring.BeansConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Unfortunately, strange things started to happen. Let me show you an example. Simplifying my class structure looks as follows:

```
@Component
public class ComponentA
{
}

@Configurable
public class BeanB
{
    @Autowired
    private ComponentA componentA;
}

@Configurable
public class BeanC
{
    @Autowired
    private ComponentA componentA;

    private BeanB beanB;

    public BeanC(BeanB beanB)
    {
        this.beanB = beanB;
    }
}

@Configurable
public class Application
{
    @Autowired
    private ComponentA componentA;

    public Application()
    {
    }

    public void init()
    {
        BeanC beanC = new BeanC(new BeanB());
    }
}
```

With the XML setup, when it does work, `ComponentA` is correctly injected by Spring into all my `@Configurable` objects.
Strangely, with annotation-only configuration `BeanC` doesn't get the `ComponentA` injected (it's always `null`), howewer `BeanB` and `Application` do get that!

Have you got any ideas why would it happen? As soon as I comment out lines in `web.xml` to go back to my previous (XML-based) configuration all starts to work.

My happy guess is that XML Spring entries register something more under the cover than their annotation based counterparts. I've spend half a day trying to find out, what could that be, but I gave up. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Real packages for your `@ComponentScan` value and `BeanC`?

Comment: You don't seem to have @Autowired on the constructor of BeanC. Have you tried that? It might also be worth making it @Autowired(required = true) to ensure that you see errors when it fails to inject.

Comment: loadtime-weaving and `@Configuration` can be a pain to get working. As soon as you reference a class and that class is loaded **BEFORE** loadtime-weaving is active there is no way the class can be enhanced anymore. The @Configuration classes are laoded, then scanned, so if one of those references `BeanC` you are screwed. With XML the loading of the classes is delayed (because they aren't part of a classfile).

Comment: @chrylis packages passed to component scan include my whole code base, so that's not a problem, but thanks.

Comment: @Steve I don't want BeanC to get BeanB via autowiring. I pass it manually. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PiotrGórny Are you using AspectJ, Spring Proxy AOP, or Spring LTW?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure if I understood you correctly - did you mean `@Configurable` classes? I'd thought that whenever I instantiate a class, which is `@Configurable` it will have `@Autowire` dependencies injected live, into just created instance...

Comment: @chrylis That's a really good question :-) I don't know to be honest. I don't set anything on `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` nor `<context:load-time-weaver />`, so please tell me :-)

Comment: @PiotrGórny Disassemble your `BeanC` constructor and see if there's a lot of `ajc` around. If not, you may not have had it compiled with the AspectJ compiler, and the difference may be one of the edge cases with AOP defaults between XML and JavaConfig.

Comment: @PiotrGórny This will only work if classes aren't already loaded **BEFORE** loadtime weaving kicks in. So if one of your `@Configuration` classes references `BeanC`  that will not be available for loadtime weaving anymore because it is already loaded. This is one of the drawbacks/problems with the @Configuration approach (classes might get loaded eagerly).

Comment: @chrylis he is using loadtime weaving NOT compile timeweaving so taking a look at the code will not show anything.

Comment: To answer another question you are using LTW because that is what you are enabling with `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` (or the xml variant of that), would be pretty useless if `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` would create AOP proxies. (Might be that something else triggers that like a `<tx:annotation-driven ../>` without `mode="aspectj"`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was wanting to confirm that the load-time weaving was being applied in the XML case. `@Configurable` can get quite weird with it.