# Issues with a Spring @Configurable class not getting its dependencies autowired

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-boot, javaagents, load-time-weaving

I am trying to configure Load Time Weaving for my Spring Boot app to properly autowire dependencies on a `@Configurable` java class.

Here is my configuration/main class:

```
package com.bignibou;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class, FlywayAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is how I start the application (my gradle build renamed the spring-instrument jar):

```
java -javaagent:build/lib/springinstrument.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

Here is the `@Configurable` class that does not get its dependencies autowired:

```
package com.bignibou.converter;

@Configurable
public class StringToDayToTimeSlotConverter implements Converter<String, DayToTimeSlot> {

    @Autowired
    private DayToTimeSlotRepository dayToTimeSlotRepository;//NOT AUTOWIRED!!

    @Override
    public DayToTimeSlot convert(String id) {
        return dayToTimeSlotRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));//NPE HERE!!
    }

}
```

Here is where the class is instantiated (with `new`):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bignibou.controller" }, useDefaultFilters = false, includeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = ControllerAdvice.class) })
@Import(ApplicationControllerAdvice.class)
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new DayToTimeSlotToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToDayToTimeSlotConverter());//INSTANTIATED HERE!
        registry.addConverter(new LanguageToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToLanguageConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new AddressToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToAddressConverter());
        super.addFormatters(registry);
    }
```

Can anyone please help figure out why `StringToDayToTimeSlotConverter`'s dependencies are not autowired?

Comment: Do you really need `@Configurable`? Why not simply declare it as a `@Bean` or `@Component` and inject all `Converter` instances in your `@Configuration` class. Trying to setup weaving just for this seems like overkill...

Comment: Hi Marten. I've actually stumbled on a relevant comment by you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193395/) and decided to do just that i.e. use @Component on my converters and autowire them. The only trouble is that I have a number of converters and I am going to have to autowire all of them making my configuration class less concise...

Comment: You can just inject a list of converters by putting `@Autowired` on a collection typed field. That way you have a single field containing all those beans. Then you can simply iterate of that list. You don't need to inject all the converters individually.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question with at least a suggestion for a solution that I will turn into an answer so that the question can be "closed". Turn `StringToDayToTimeSlotConverter` into a Bean as follows:

```java
@Bean
public class StringToDayToTimeSlotConverter implements Converter<String, DayToTimeSlot> {

    @Autowired
    private DayToTimeSlotRepository dayToTimeSlotRepository;

    @Override
    public DayToTimeSlot convert(String id) {
        return dayToTimeSlotRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));
    }
}
```

Inject all available converters in `WebMvcConfiguration` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bignibou.controller" }, useDefaultFilters = false, includeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = ControllerAdvice.class) })
@Import(ApplicationControllerAdvice.class)
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    List<Converter> converters;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        for (Converter converter : converter) {
            registry.addConverter(converter);
        }
        super.addFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```